# Count number of unique indices using Cplex

Tags: cplex

For my consolidation problem, I want to count the number of unique values that my decision variable `dvar int+ y[terminal, consolidated_truck, time, order] in 0..1; //y is 1 if order n is consolidated at terminal i in consolidated truck c at time t` takes for the consolidated trucks. If I simply compute `forall(i in terminal, t in time, n in order) sum(c in consolidated_trucks) y[i,c,t,n] == trucks_used;` I get every value, while I just want to obtain all unique values for c. Is there a function in Cplex where I can count this or a way to formulate it correctly?

Thank you very much for your help!
Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A starting point in [Easy optimization](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-decision-optimization-simple-alex-fleischer/) : [count true constraints](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zoocounttrueconstraints.mod)

```
int nbKids=300;

// a tuple is like a struct in C, a class in C++ or a record in Pascal
tuple bus
{
  key int nbSeats;
  float cost;
}

// This is a tuple set
{bus} buses={<40,500>,
    <30,400>,
    <35,450>,
    <20,300>};

// asserts help make sure data is fine
assert forall(b in buses) b.nbSeats>0;
assert forall(b in buses) b.cost>0;

// decision variable array
dvar int+ nbBus[buses];

// objective
minimize
     sum(b in buses) b.cost*nbBus[b];
     
// constraints
subject to
{
   sum(b in buses) b.nbSeats*nbBus[b]>=nbKids;
   
   // Number of sizes where we have 1 or 2 buses should be at least 3
   
   sum(b in buses) (1<=nbBus[b]<=2) >=3;
}
```

or even

```
int nbKids=300;

// a tuple is like a struct in C, a class in C++ or a record in Pascal
tuple bus
{
  key int nbSeats;
  float cost;
}

// This is a tuple set
{bus} buses={<40,500>,
    <30,400>,
    <35,450>,
    <20,300>};

// asserts help make sure data is fine
assert forall(b in buses) b.nbSeats>0;
assert forall(b in buses) b.cost>0;

range quantity = 0..10;

// decision variable array
dvar int+ nbBus[buses] in quantity;

// objective
minimize
     sum(b in buses) b.cost*nbBus[b];
     
// constraints
subject to
{
   sum(b in buses) b.nbSeats*nbBus[b]>=nbKids;
   
   // Quantities should have less than 1 value
   


     sum(q in quantity)
        (1<=sum(b in buses) (q==nbBus[b])) <=1;
   }
```

from [count values](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zoocountvalues.mod)